# How do Azure Function Bindings work when called from other Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, binding, azure-functions

Trying to create two functions.  An HTTP Trigger handles the response back to the sender and it will also in-process call the second function to save to queue.

I would like to remove the Service Bus binding from the trigger function and have a return binding that works that way.

Calling the second function by `SecureGuard.ServiceBusOutput` runs the logic perfectly fine but nothing happens to the queue.  The first function, as it currently is works perfectly fine and the queue is populated with the provisioned data.  This is just for testing / learning, there is no real requirement.

```cs
public static class SecureGuard
{
    [FunctionName("HttpTrigger")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [ServiceBus("secure-guard-currency-queue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ICollector<object> output,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

        string responseMessage;
        
        SecureGuard.ServiceBusOutput(data, log); // Runs ok but does not return binding

        output.Add(data); // This binding works successfully.

        responseMessage = $"Your request has been recorded with the following payload: {data}";
        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }

    // When trying to call this function from above.  Return binding does not work.
    [FunctionName("ServiceBusOutput")]
    [return: ServiceBus("secure-guard-currency-queue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
    public static string ServiceBusOutput([HttpTrigger] dynamic input, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Incoming Data Pushed to ServiceBus Queue: {input}");
        return input;
    }
}
```

I would like to understand why the second binding is not working. Is it because the return binding is being ignored given its originating from another Azure Function, rather than the Azure App itself?

What's considered best practice here as the Functions grow and multiple bindings may be required?  I've also found documentation that.

```cs
[FunctionName("MyFunctionName")]
public static async void Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string queueName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("QueueName");
    string serviceBusConnectionString =
        System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    var client = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, queueName);
    var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody));
    await client.SendAsync(message);
}
```

I have also found the above code from: [Azure Service Bus bindings and triggers for Azure Functions](https://purple.telstra.com/blog/azure-service-bindings-and-triggers-azure-functions) which describes a way to contact a queue without a binding.  I haven't tested it, but I'm assuming that this would work in this case.

Comment: If you want to call `ServiceBusOutput` from `HttpTrigger` why not just perform an http request since `ServiceBusOutput` is http triggered? My best guess is that by calling the function method directly some vital parts orchestrated by the platform are not executed.

Comment: @PeterBons Not sure I understand what you're referring to with HTTP Request.  I'm listening for an HTTP transmission to then push it on the service bus queue.  There is some validation I do which I omitted from the above code snippet to keep focus on the question.

Comment: Function Chaning with Durable Function do what you are looking for I'd say https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sequence?tabs=csharp

Comment: Thanks for the response @silent will take a look